# animate with delay throwing error delay is not a method

Tags: jquery

I want to animate a div from top to bottom 50 px , and wait 5 seconds
and bottom to top again, i am getting error saying delay is not supported

```
$("#div").animate({ 
             top: "+=50px"                     
       }, 1000).delay(5000).animate({ 
           top: "-=50px" 
       },1000, function() { 
             // animation done
         });
```

any help will be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Jquery 1.4? The delay method was added in version 1.4 of JQuery. To check you can run:

```
alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
```

Comment: @user , thanks i have two jquery's in this page , one old and one new , you gave me the right direction , this is due to duplicates. thanks